# DependencyObject is not updating the View

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a ViewModel that is a `DependencyObject` for which the `DependencyProperty`s are not updating the View with the new values.

A sample property (the get/set wrapper is called as expected)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty WeaponNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "WeaponName",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(WeaponSystemVM),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnWeaponNameChanged)));
    public string WeaponName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(WeaponNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WeaponNameProperty, value); }
    }
```

The `Callback` (called when `WeaponName` is changed)

```
private static void OnWeaponNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WeaponSystemVM vm = d as WeaponSystemVM;
    if (vm != null)
    { vm.CommandAddWeaponSystem.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); }
}
```

The CanExecute `Delegate` (gets run as expected and updates the relevant `Button`)

```
private bool CanAddSystem()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeaponName)) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeaponLock)) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeaponDamage)) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeaponAttack)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

The input `TextBox`

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameInput" Text="{Binding WeaponName, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="12,4" RelativePanel.Below="NameAdorner" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                     RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
```

The output `TextBlock` (is NOT updated with the new value and the `DataContext` is the same as the input `TextBox`)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding WeaponName}"/>
```

Frustratingly, it seems to be just this implementation that isn't working.
In an attempt to reproduce the issue, I created a seperate project without all the extra info associated with my app, and the View is being updated exactly as expected.

What I don't understand is what is not being done correctly in this implementation. The ViewModel is updating exactly as expected. The Bindings are valid according to the `LiveVisualTree`.
Can anyone point me to the issue?

Comment: I dunno why you would create a VM that inherits from a UI class. It feels wrong to me. You normally create properties with INPC instead of dependency properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `DependencyProperty`s in your ViewModel: it is a markup class, used for binding on the View side. Overkill and out of scope for it being used that way.
You should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7), and fire the [`INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netframework-4.7) event in every single property you want to notify the UI about.
Something like:

your ViewModel inherits from

```
public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetAndRaiseIfChanged<T>(
        ref T backingField,
        T newValue,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(backingField, newValue))
            return;

        backingField = newValue;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

and in your ViewModel you define your property like

```
private string _weaponName;
public string WeaponName
{
    get { return this._weaponName; }
    set { SetAndRaiseIfChanged(ref this._weaponName, value); }
}
```

a more concise CanAddSystem

```
private bool CanAddSystem()
{
    return 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeaponName)
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeaponLock)
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeaponDamage)
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeaponAttack);
}
```

build your ViewModel's command with something that implements [`ICommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=netframework-4.7) interface (something like a RelayCommand)

the View piece would be

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding WeaponName}"/>
```

and you're done: when you bind an ICommand to the UI, the system automatically updates the CanExecute reading it from the ViewModel.

Comment: I have actually been using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `RelayCommand` so far, which has been working, but had seemed to me to be very messy and rather manual to track and update properties (though your base class above is much nicer than what I have). I was experimenting with the `DependencyObject` route for the more automated side of things. I also read its lighter on the system. I guess I will continue along that path then. However, the above issue with the view not updating is still not actually resolved - Any advice on what the issue there is?